# How to use CMake to find and link OpenGL(mesa) package in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, opengl, cmake, mesa

I am totally new in *CMake* and *OpenGL*. I now need to use *OpenGL* as a library in my project on my Ubuntu 15.04 64bit PC, which is built by *CMake 3.0.2*.

I have been working on this several days, nearly frustrated. I get confused with a bunch of problems.

---

#### mesa and OpenGL

First of all, I installed the *mesa* package with command `sudo apt-get install mesa-common-dev`, which get me *mesa 10.5.2*.

Then I browse the package files with `dpkg -L mesa-common-dev`:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/bug
...
/usr/share/bug/mesa-common-dev/control

/usr/share/doc
...
/usr/share/doc/mesa-common-dev/faq.html

/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/dri.pc

/usr/include
/usr/include/GL
/usr/include/GL/gl.h
...
/usr/include/GL/glx_mangle.h
```

**QUESTION 1**: Where are the shared libraries (.so) and static libraries (.a)?

---

#### CMake

I now have a `CMakeLists.txt`, with the OpenGL module named `OPENGL`

```
...
find_package(OPENGL REQUIRED)  # here is CMakeLists.txt:45
...
include_directories(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${OPENGL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(MyProj ... ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})
...
```

So I definitely need to have a cmake file, say `FindOPENGL.cmake`, like this (took `GLEW`'s cmake file as a template):

```
# OPENGL_FOUND             If OPENGL is found
# OPENGL_LIBRARIES         OPENGL libraries
# OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS      OPENGL include directories
# OPENGL_LIBRARY_DIRS      OPENGL library directories

if(UNIX)
  set(OPENGL_INC_NAMES gl.h)
  set(OPENGL_LIB_NAMES libGL.so.1.2.0)
endif(UNIX)

# OPENGL static library     # line 17
find_library(OPENGL_LIBRARIES
    NAMES ${OPENGL_LIB_NAMES}
    PATHS /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa
    DOC "OPENGL library")

# OPENGL library dir        # line 23
find_path(OPENGL_LIBRARY_DIRS
    NAMES ${OPENGL_LIB_NAMES}
    PATHS /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa
    DOC "OPENGL include directories")

# OPENGL include dir        # line 29
find_path(OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS
    NAMES ${OPENGL_INC_NAMES}
    PATHS /usr/include/GL
    DOC "OPENGL include directories")

# Version
set(OPENGL_VERSION 1.13.0)

# Set package standard args
include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS(OPENGL       # here is FindOPENGL.cmake:40
    REQUIRED_VARS OPENGL_LIBRARIES OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS OPENGL_LIBRARY_DIRS
    VERSION_VAR OPENGL_VERSION)
```

**QUESTION 2**: How to link static libraries and shared libraries in cmake file, and what is the difference between line 17/23/29?

I then run cmake and get following errors:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:136 (message):
  Cound NOT find OPENGL (missing: OPENGL_LIBRARIES OPENGL_LIBRARY_DIRS)
  (found version "1.13.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:343 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/modules/FindOPENGL.cmake:40 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:45 (find_package)
```

**QUESTION 3**: How come I get this error and how can I fix it? Did I do something wrong through the whole procedure?

---

#### Update

Thanks for @usr1234567 's answer, I then delete my `FindOPENGL.cmake` and try to make use of [/usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/FindOpenGL.cmake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindOpenGL.html). I still get the error `missing: OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY`. I look into this cmake file for the definition of `OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY`, and manually check the lib paths in it, unfortunately none of the paths listed exists.

Did I install mesa properly?

Comment: Try installing freeglut3-dev, that should pull all required packages for OpenGL dependencies.

Comment: @usr1234567 I have to use some other libraries alternative to freeglut3, anyway, your comment inspired me a lot, the problem is I did not get all required packages.

Comment: @usr1234567 unfortunately other linked error occurs ...

Comment: So CMake does no longer emit the warning you have in your question? Then accept my answer and maybe post a new one. The current question is already so specific, it will not help many others.

Comment: With all of these packages installed, I can generate Makefile with cmake correctly: 


    mesa-common-dev
    mesa-utils-extra
    libgl1-mesa-dev
    libglu1-mesa-dev
    libglapi-mesa
    libx11-dev
    libxi-dev
    libxinerama-dev
    libxcursor-dev
    libxrandr-dev

Comment: Installing mesa-utils-extra alone did it for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Use CMake FindOpenGL, see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindOpenGL.html.
- The difference between lines 17 and 23 is that you look for a library (find_library in line 17) and for headers (find_path in line 23). In line 23 and 29 you look for gl.h in two different locations. Overall, this does not matter as you should write your own find routine because CMake provides one for you.
- You can find static and shared libraries. By default you get the .so. For a second run / variable "Just ask for the archive name first: `find_library(MYLIB NAMES libmylib.a mylib)`" from https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2010-December/041326.html
- Question 3 could be solved by hinting CMake where to look. This can be done by adding the right path to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH. In your case it should be found if you use FindOpenGL from CMake.

Comment: thanks for your answer. By the way, find_path is for .h while find_library is for .a, how does cmake deal with shared library .so

Comment: I then use the `FindOpenGL.cmake` from CMake, still have error `missing: OpenGL_gl_LIBRARY`, I print `OPENGL_FOUND OPENGL_XMESA_FOUND OPENGL_GLU_FOUND OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR OPENGL_LIBRARIES OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY` in my `CMakeLists.txt`, none of these variables defined except `OPENGL_FOUND=FALSE`. How can I make use of OpenGL properly?

Answer (score 2):

As stated, use the built-in `FindOpenGL.cmake` provided by cmake.

You're missing `libgl1-mesa-dev`. So try this instead:

```
sudo apt install mesa-common-dev libgl1-mesa-dev
```

And optionally, if you want EGL to be found by `FindOpenGL.cmake`:

```
sudo apt install mesa-common-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libgles2-mesa-dev
```